# Add toString method to class using AspectJ

Tags: aop, aspectj

I have a class which I can't modify but I want to change the behaviour of one of it's methods.

```java
public class TestClass {
}
```

I would like to pointcut the toString method inside of it so instead of returning "TestClass@a8d8as" it will return "hello".

```java
@Around("execution(* *(..)) && this(com.test.TestClass)")
```

This works If I define the toString method inside TestClass, but won't work with the implicit one.

I haven't worked with aspects for a long time and I'm quite new at them, is there something I'm missing or a way to do what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try using AspectJ inter-type declarations to implement `toString()`.

Comment: At the end I went to the lower-level and added the method using javassist, but it looks like aspectj inter-type would be the solution here (didn't know it existed) using aspects (I didn't need aspect, just wanted to override a concrete toString).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for an AspectJ solution despite having solved the problem via Javassist. So here it is according to Nándor's suggestion:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class TestClass {
  private String tableName;

  public TestClass(String tableName) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new TestClass("Invoice"));
    System.out.println(new TestClass("InvoiceItem"));
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.TestClass;

public privileged aspect ToStringAspect {
  public String TestClass.toString() {
    return tableName;
  }
}
```

Console log:

```
Invoice
InvoiceItem
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to self-answer, its not the correct answer (if someone can answer to the original, even though not needed now, could be nice), but allowed me to do what I wanted.

As I just wanted to add toString to a Class, I've changed the aproach and went with JavaAssist directly

```java
import javassist.ClassPool
import javassist.ClassClassPath

val pool = ClassPool.getDefault
ClassPool.getDefault.insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(this.getClass))
val cc = pool.get("TestClass")
cc.defrost()

val m = CtNewMethod.make(
  "public String toString() { return this.TableName }",
  cc
);
cc.addMethod(m);
cc.toClass
```